# How to generate a time series data with multiple columns in R from sample data

Tags: r, time-series

I looking for generating 100 instances of time series data with 4 columns per instance namely timestamp, alpha, beta, gama in R. I want to generate such data 100 times varying in amplitude and frequency. My time stamp field is for 30sec and for each second I want 50 samples. Sample data of 30sec of one instance looks like this:

```
Time stamp, alpha, beta, gama
2015-09-26 13:27:41 , 4.87243379 ,-11.53702253, 0.69133098
2015-09-26 13:27:41,-1.29121787,-16.90953396,0.37391231
2015-09-26 13:27:41,-9.50204804,-12.72212861,2.82708876
2015-09-26 13:27:41,-11.14254103,-4.97144091,2.73346744
```

[Graph of this data looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpAiL.jpg)

How can I generate data for 100 times? Is there a way to do using `ts` function in R. Any kind of help or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for reply G. Gronthendieck. I looked into arima.sim. I want to generate 50 samples for 1 sec. My data has a specific pattern which is closer to sin wave function when plotted. How can I write such a fuction and use it in arima.sim? Is there any function that can be used to fit my data. ? Thanks in advance.